# Google Map with vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am creating an application in vb where I need to attach the Google map with the application.
I have used the webbrowser for this and have added "http://maps.google.com/.. in the query address. This seems to work fine hoever my problem is I dnt want the complete google map webpage to be shown in the from, I just want the map portion to appear in the form. This is something which am not able to achieve. Could you ppplease help me on this? Thanks. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

You could [embed the Google Map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) onto some webpage of yours and then direct the WebBrowser to this web page.